# The solution to restore user password by sending the lost password via the registered email address?

Tags: c#, winforms, email, network-programming, smtp

I want to add this feature to my application. It works OK but I'm afraid of a problem here. At first, I'll talk a little about how I implement the feature. Simply, the user has to register his email address first (at the registration time). If he loses his password, he can click on a link to activate the sender. This sender will send the password (corresponding to his username) to his registered email address. I think there should have many kinds of sender here and I'm using SmtpClient to send the email. This Smtp needs a NetworkCredential, and I provide it with some valid and active Credential. I have to create some user accounts (in Gmail and Yahoo networks), apply these accounts information as the credentials for my Smtp.

Here is the problem, my Password restoring feature won't work if all those credentials being invalid or inactive. I mean if all the user accounts (I created in Gmail and Yahoo mail) somehow are inactive, the Smtp will be unable to send the email. The most popular reason for those accounts being inactive is **there hasn't been any access/login to them for a long time (e.g: about 3 months)** It is almost certain that it will happen, except I have to remind myself to login to those accounts periodically to keep them active.

I wonder if there is any solution for this? I've thought of keeping those accounts information in a config file but the customer won't know how to edit that config file to change the sender credential information and even they know how to, that's so inconvenient. I've also thought of popping up a window requiring information for the sender credential from user (user may use his own email account or has to create a new one), it's also inconvenient, I think so. I've also think of logging to those accounts (via my application) periodically (about once a month) to keep them active. But I wonder if there is a better solution, plus that requires the user computer to be connected to Internet and this is not always met (even there is a situation that the user computer is always off line for months or years, but suddenly one day, he loses his password, he wants to get it back and at that time, he connects his computer to the Internet and uses the password restoring feature, but he can't because all the accounts built-in for the sender credentials has been inactive because of not having any access/login to them for months/years).

Do you have any idea on how to solve this problem?

## UPDATE

I'm sorry to who suggested me that there is a security flaw here but I just want a solution for the password restoration. If you are kind enough please let me know what the security flaw is in detail. As I mentioned above, there is of course a security flaw because of the user password (a plain text) is saved in memory. But that's just a demo and it's only for demonstrative purpose for my real problem which is sending the user a new password (or any kind of authoritative access info). Here is what I want to explain more:

1. Suppose user's password is: Iloveprogramming
2. After hashed, it should be 3920bdbd4c000dd392e2501e89747173
3. That's all my application knows about user's access info.
4. When user typed in his password correctly, that entered password should be hashed into the same string above and this will be compared against the hashed string stored in the database and he should be logged in.
5. Now if he forgets his password, What can I do?

Here is the way most of websites do for us (who unfortunately forget our passwords):
   - Support a link like "Forgot your password?"
   - Clicking the link will lead you to a page like this:
         ->  Supply your user name:  ............
         ->  Click OK (or any submit button) to get your new password.

I would like to do the same with my application. This is a windows forms application. I know that the content sent to the user email address should only be some confirmation link (about the password restoration), not a password (this is known only by the user who uses the email the password is sent to, however other users may disturb him by clicking on the 'Forgot password' link and fill in his user name). But it is only a must-do for a multi-user application, my application is in fact for only 1 user using on his own machine. What is the flaw?

Here is what I intend to do:

1. Auto-Generates the password, hashes this password and saves that hashed string into the database as the new hashed password for him. After that, send this auto-generated password immediately to his email address.
2. Dispose the string which stores the newly generated password.

What is the flaw here? And if it does exist, please let me know another solution for this? I'm just afraid of the email account which is used to send the password to my user's email address may not work (inactive) in future for some reason (as I said, not logging in for a long time).

Please feel free to explain the flaw detail in an answer, it may not answer to my original question but it does help me and I would accept that answer. Thank you!

Again, I don't have money for a dedicated website for the password restoring feature of my winforms application.

Comment: There are major security flaws here. You shouldn't even know the password, let alone send it around in plaintext. Instead of sending the new password, you should send a link to the change-password page, with a one-time ticket in the URL that logs him in.

Comment: @EJP I don't think it is so serious, my application is a Winforms application, I don't have a dedicated webpage for that purpose. I don't think there is a major security flaw here. The problem is I'm afraid the email accounts used to send the password become inactive for the reason I mentioned in my question. Thanks!

Comment: You ask people what they think, and when they think you've got a security flaw, you ignore them. You _do_ have a security flaw. Your application should never know the user's password.

Comment: @John Saunders Wow,I'm creating my application as a demo version, in fact the password is not hashed using md5 or any other, but the idea is the same here.My application of course shouldn't know the user password, it just hashes the password user typed in and compare it with the stored hashed password in the database. But when user forgets his password, my application should randomly autogenerates a password for him and send him this randomly generated password.This is done by most of website-based service but my case is a Winforms application and I don't intend to use a dedicated site for it.